# Android jsoup get text

Tags: android, jsoup

I need to get text from

```
<div class="page-header">
<h1> معاني الأسماء التي تبدأ بحرف <font class="srch_expl_word">الف</font> في قاموس المعاني صفحة 1</h1>
</div>
```

I have tried this:-

```
     Elements dec = doc.select("h1");
     str = dec.text().toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

`select("h1")` returns an "array" of elements. You probably should get the first element of `dec` and then get it's text.

I've just tested it and this solution worked with **jsoup version 1.8.3**.

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.almaany.com/ar/name/").get();
    Elements dec = doc.select("h1");
    Element neededH1 = dec.first();
    String text = neededH1.text();
    System.out.println("Your text here [" + text + "]"); //معاني الأسماء
```

Comment: its gave me nullpointerexep

Comment: @user2764693 at which row?

Comment: String str = neededH1.text().toString();

Comment: @user2764693 is it after calling `toString()` or `text()`? I mean is `neededH1` null or not?

Comment: the error is in the code line with String str = neededH1.text().toString();

Comment: @user2764693 I've updated my answer. In what line the error is now?

Comment: same line with neededH1

Comment: @user2764693 It means, that `h1` is not present in your `doc`. I suggest you check the `doc` variable. How is it defined?

Comment: this the doc:  doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.almaany.com/ar/name/").get();

Comment: @user2764693 are you sure the URL `almaany.com/ar/name/` returns an `html` page?

Comment: how can I check that ?  I have tried to get the meta describtion and the title and its worked fine

Comment: @user2764693 try to call `doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.almaany.com/ar/name/").get();`

Comment: same thing i also tried Element neededH1 = dec.get(0);

Comment: @user2764693 I've updated the answer again with solution that worked for me. Hope that helps!

Comment: I still have the same error !!!!!

Comment: it was my bad .... doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.almaany.com/ar/name/%D8%A7/4/").get();

Comment: it works fine thankss

Comment: @user2764693 you should accept this answer....